# Type Error: require(...) is not a function in SendGrid NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid

I am trying to send emails using the following doc on sendrid:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/nodejs.html

My app.js looks like this:

```
var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')('SENDGRID_APIKEY');
```

When runnig npm start I get the following error:

```
var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')(conf);
                               ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Grandullon\Desktop\angular\app.js:8:36)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Grandullon\Desktop\angular\bin\www:7:11)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? conf is a variable where I store my API key.

I am using a clean express installation.

THANKS

My package.json can be looked here as requested:

http://pastebin.com/pGKWFReX

Comment: Could show us your package.json file?

Comment: Yeah, the issue isn't there in package.json, my bad. Look ot @Akash's answer which is on point with what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [latest documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/USAGE.md) shows a different structure for initialization.

You should try doing

```
var sg = require('sendgrid').SendGrid(conf);
```

Comment: Using that initialization works !!! So I think the other version must stop working then. I will contact SendGrid support to check. THANKS

Comment: I think the older version would work if you download the older version of package. If some business requirement forces you to use older api, you can always switch to `npm install sendgrid-nodejs@2` although I dunno if Sendgrid will support that.

Comment: Awesone, I will give it a try. I am just testing the service so no business requirement at hand.